# Group action derived from the product of two groups operating on a set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ (resp. $H$) be a group operating on a set $E$ on the left (resp. right). Suppose that

$$(g.x).h=g.(x.h)\text{ for }g\in G,x\in E,\text{ and }h\in H.$$

Let $H^{op}$ denote the opposite group of $H$, $\mathfrak{S}_{E}$ denote the symmetric group of the set $E$, and let $*$ denote the law of composition on $H^{op}$. The law of composition on $G\times H^{op}$ is defined component-wise.

**Claim.** The mapping 
$$\Phi :G\times H^{op}\rightarrow\mathfrak{S}_{E},\ (g,h)\mapsto(x\mapsto g.x.h)$$
is a left operation of $G\times H^{op}$ on $E$.

**My attempt**:

Let $$\phi_{1}:G\rightarrow\mathfrak{S}_{E},\ g\mapsto(x\mapsto g.x)$$ $$\phi_{2}:H^{op}\rightarrow\mathfrak{S}_{E},\ h\mapsto(x\mapsto x.h)$$ denote the actions of $G$ and $H^{op}$ respectively. Applying the following result seems to yield the required homomorphism:

> Let $(\phi_{i}:G_{i}\rightarrow K)_{i\in I}$ be a family of
>   homomorphisms of groups with operators such that, for all $i\in I$ and
>   $j\in I$ with $i\neq j$, $x\in G_{i}$, $y\in G_{j}$, the elements
>   $\phi_{i}(x)$ and $\phi_{j}(y)$ of $K$ commute; there exists one and
>   only one homomorphism of groups with operators $$\Phi:\bigoplus
> G_{i}\rightarrow K$$ such that $\phi_{i}=\Phi\circ\iota_{i}$ for all
>   $i\in I$. For every element $x$ of $\bigoplus G_{i}$,
>   $\Phi(x)=\Pi\phi_{i}(x_i)$.
>
> Note that
>
> $$\bigoplus G_{i}=\{x\in\prod G_{i}:|\{i\in I\ |x_{i}\neq
>  e_{i}\}|\in\mathbb{N}\},$$
>
> and for every $j\in I$ $$\iota_{j}:G_{j}\rightarrow\bigoplus G_{i}$$
>   defined by $\iota_{j}(x)=(x_{i})_{i\in I}$, where $\iota_{j}(x)(j)=x$
>   and $\iota_{j}(x)(i)=e_{i}$ for $i\neq j$.

Therefore, in our case, we have $\Phi(g,h)=\phi_1(g)\circ\phi_2(h)=\phi_{2}(h)\circ\phi_1(g)$.

Now, let's check whether this homomorphism is a left operation on E:

$$ \Phi(e_{G},e_{H})=\phi_1(e_{G})\circ\phi_2(e_{H})=id_{E}\circ id_{E}=id_{E};$$

$$ \Phi((g,h)(g',h'))=\Phi(gg',h*h')=\phi_1(gg')\circ\phi_2(h*h')=\phi_1(gg')\circ\phi_2(h'h)
\\=\phi_1(g)\circ \phi_2(g')\circ\phi_2(h')\circ\phi_2(h)=\phi_1(g)\circ\Phi(g',h')\circ\phi_2(h)...?$$

I'm not sure what to do now to finish the proof of this last property: i.e., to show $$\Phi((g,h)(g',h'))=\Phi(g,h)\circ\Phi(g',h').$$

Is the my homomorphism wrong or am I missing something?

Any hints would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Okay my mistake was very basic: treating the right action of H (incorrectly) as a left action.

Let's try the proof again:

$$\begin{align}
\Phi((g,h),(g',h'))&=\Phi(gg',h*h')\\
&=\phi_{1}(gg')\circ\phi_{2}(h*h')\\
&=\phi_{1}(gg')\circ\phi_{2}(h'h)\\
&=\phi_{1}(gg')\circ\phi_{2}(h)\circ\phi_{2}(h')\\
&=\phi_{1}(g)\circ\phi_{1}(g')\circ\phi_{2}(h)\circ\phi_{2}(h')\\
&=\phi_{1}(g)\circ\phi_{2}(h)\circ\phi_{1}(g')\circ\phi_{2}(h')\\
&=\Phi(g,h)\circ\Phi(g',h').
\end{align}$$